# Chrome extension - not able to re-start scrolling interval after initial stop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension needs to scroll to the bottom of the page smoothly, which works perfectly. The scrolling stops fine upon `request.doScroll` change to `false`. However, if I try to re-enable the scrolling it does not re-engage.
Any ideas why and how can I achieve the stop\start and so on functionality?

```
//starts fine for the first time and does not start for the second time
if(request.doScroll){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {
                code:`
                    let x = 1; //y-axis pixel displacement
                    let y = 1; //delay in milliseconds
                    const t = setInterval(()=> {
                        window.scroll(0, x);
                        x = x + 5; //to increase speed increase increment interval

                        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
                            console.log("clearing scrolling interval");
                            clearInterval(t);
                        }

                    }, y);
                    
                    `
            });
            }else{

                chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id,
                    {
                        //this stops the scrolling
                        code: "clearInterval(t);"
                    }
                );
            }
```

Comment: I guess request.doScroll is a value that toggle on a click event on context document.. code: clearInterval(t) in else block throw some errors in console?

Comment: actually `clearInterval(t)` does work and the scrolling does stop. however, re-enabling `request.doScroll` does not re-engage in scrolling. Do you have an idea why? Ive edited the original post

Comment: well, now try to change "const t" in "var t". Could be this the issue. To verify!

Comment: Just tried, not working :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change "if" block with this:

```
        code:`
            var t;
            var x;  //y-axis pixel displacement
            (_ => {
            let y = 1; //delay in milliseconds
            t = setInterval(()=> {
                window.scroll(0, x);
                x = (x||1) + 5; //to increase speed increase increment interval

                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
                    console.log("clearing scrolling interval");
                    clearInterval(t);
                    x = 1   /* only if you want...*/
                }

            }, y);
            })()`
```

Comment: Almost perfect, its starting again but always from the top of the page. I'm trying this code to start from the current scroll position, maybe somehow with `document.documentElement.scrollTop`?

Comment: amazing, does exactly what I need

Comment: Do you know by a chance why the script stops scrolling when I switch to another tab?